# get running job sidekiq from worker (ruby)

Tags: ruby, sidekiq, delayed-job, sidekiq-monitor

```
workers = Sidekiq::Workers.new
workers.each do |_process_id, _thread_id, work|
  p work['payload']['jid']
end
```

How can I get the job from the worker?

I have the jid but job aren't in Queue because still running...

Comment: You might query [`stats`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/v5.2.1/lib/sidekiq/api.rb#L106).

Comment: What do you mean by "get the job" at this point?

Comment: @lacostenycoder exactly like you do in your post (first exemple), to get arguments of jobs for exemple

Comment: @Matrix so does that work for you?

Comment: no because we can't select a job when queue is empty. Maybe the job is delete when worker running it?

Comment: @lacostenycoder I too am looking for a way to get the job details from within a Worker's perform method. Specifically, we would like to access the enqueued_at property that each job payload includes.

Comment: @Matrix the job should not be deleted unless it completes or if it fails, with no retry set, it should end up in the dead queue.

Comment: @SkylarGraika see my updated answer below. It may help you find what you need.